# Django Polls Tutorial No changes detected in app polls

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm going through the Django Polls tutorial, and I'm trying the command "python manage.py makemigrations polls", and I keep getting the message "No changes detected in app 'polls'"

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or how I could do it differently, or what the message even means.

EDIT for clarity:

I expect something somewhat like the printout on the tutorial:

```
Migrations for 'polls':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Question
    - Create model Choice
```

And then later in the tutorial, when it requests I type the command `python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001`, that I get some sort of printout like the one shown (which is rather long).  I'm working off the tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Instead, I get

```
CommandError: Cannot find a migration matching 'polls' form app '0001'. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
```

Comment: What are you expecting from running the command?  If you've run this before, it might be because there's actually no changes in your models.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit with more information.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that'll give us a better idea of how to troubleshoot.  In your 'settings.py' file, is 'polls' listed in the 'INSTALLED_APPS'?

Comment: Yes (I think so).  In the INSTALLED_APPS = part, the last line (before the closing parentheses) reads `'polls',`.  Is it supposed to say `'djano.contrib.polls',`?

Comment: When I remove the line containing `'polls'` from the 'settings.py' fille, I get a completely different error message.  `App 'polls' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?`

Comment: You had it correct with just 'polls' in your settings.py.  Hmm, that's really strange.  It sounds like the migration might have taken place already.  Can you run 'python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001' and see what SQL shows up?

Comment: `CommandError: Cannot find a migration matching 'polls' form app '0001'. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?`  I put that one at the bottom of the edit.  That particular return was what prompted this question, because I can't seem to continue with the tutorial.

Maybe I should just uninstall and re-install everything and try again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58053/discussion-between-will-and-rod).

Comment: For me this problem was caused stupidly because I had created models.py in the mysite directory rather than the polls directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue ended up being that models.py wasn't filled out before the migration.  It should look like this.

**models.py** file:

```
from django.db import models 

class Question(models.Model): 
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published') 


class Choice(models.Model): 
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question) 
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Also be sure that 'polls' is listed in the 'INSTALLED_APPS' of your 'settings.py' file.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same error only discover that VSCode was not on AutoSave mode being a new system/installation of VSCode. If the tutorial is followed correctly, the only instance of failure should be if the models.py in the 'polls' directly was not saved properly before running the migration.