# Django 1.7 - makemigrations not creating initial migration

Tags: django, migration

Almost identical issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969471/django-polls-tutorial-no-changes-detected-in-app-polls) question, but the answer to that question does not resolve my issue as my models do not have managed=false.

I upgraded to the release version of Django 1.7, and I'm trying to migrate my apps. Some of the apps migrated, but a couple are giving me "No changes detected in app". There is no initial migration for these apps yet. When I run migrate, It includes these apps in the unmigrated apps list, but I want them in the migrated apps list as I have dependencies on them in other migrated apps, and according to the docs, that's bad ("It is not advised to have apps without migrations depend on (have a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField to) apps with migrations").

How do I migrate these apps? Do I just create an empty migration and apply it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder named `migrations` in your app folder. Then run `makemigrations` to generate `0001_initial.py` and `__init__.py`